# Optimized way to solve the following

Tags: python, sql, django, optimization

Let's assume I have a database table of map coordinates x and y. I fetch the ones I want to display and create map image using PIL.

I create an image, loop through each map tile to paste background image on it, everything is fine.

Now, there can be n players on the tile, a monster, a npc, a portal or anything else.
If there is any object on the tile I need to paste a specific image.

**Problem: how to check whether there is something on the tile? What DB structure should be?**

Every player has position (FK to MapTile of its position). If I query DB to find out where there is any player/monster/npc on tile it would be painful, so I add a column objects_count to each coordinate. If it is > 0 then I look for occurences.

Then it looks like:

```
if objects_count:
    if query_for_players_exists:
        show player
    elif query_for_monster_exists:
        show monster
    elif query_for_npc...
        show npc
    and so on.
```

I could use M2M to a table with generic relations, but IMHO generic relations aren't that fast.
Keeping in mind that queryset consists of 49 tiles how can I easily find out what object is present on the tile?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my head, was the following. If density of objects is not very high (e.g. less than 15%, for example, this is calculable), you may have table with these fields: `x, y, objects`. Where `objects` might be pickled array or some other textual representation of a list. A list of tile names.

If your map is dense enough though, you'd better split it into square non-overlapping chunks and save them as matricies of objects (the size of matrix is constant and depends on viewport size). Of course, objects itself must be serialized into matrix cells as well.

But one thing is defenetly true, that you can't gain much performance "plain" representation of objects. You need to pack them some way to reduce row-level operations.

Answer (score 0):

Why run queries for each tile or each tile+possible object? Run 1 query to bring back all the objects for all your tiles and iterate through your resultset by tile.

Even if you have 100 objects per tile with 49 tiles that is only 4900 items in your result set.

```
fetch database rows and store resultset in some data structure
foreach tile
  if( have tile in DB resultset)
    place all object from tile
```

Comment: It is one query. The question is how to fetch objects positioned in these tiles.

Comment: Ah. I mis-interprested the pseudocode then to mean you were running multiple DB queries.